# Multiple Field Validtor doesn't get binding value from other div

Tags: jsf-2

We have a multi field validator with field across two DIVs ,if we try to bind value across the fields and pass it as attributes to one of the validator ,it doesn't get the submitted value....The field phone 3 got a validator ,but when it goes to validator the submitted value is coming as null.

I have three divs "phone1" , "phone2" , "phone3" ,I would like to validate in the field "phone3" across these three fields. The validator doesn't get the submitted values of left and middle fields .I added the extra input field "confirm" inside the div "phone3" and the validtor gets the value of the "confirm" field

```
<div class="home_phone">

        <div id="phone1" >
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <h:inputText id="phonePrefix"
                maxlength="4" value="#{phoneNumberTO.phonePrefix}"
                immediate="true"
                binding="#{phonePrefix}">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>

</div>
        <div id="phone2" >


        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <h:inputText  id="phoneAreaCode"
                maxlength="4" 
                immediate="true"
                binding="#{phoneAreaCode}">
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
</div>
        <span class="sep_field">-</span>
        <div id="phone3" >

        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <h:inputText  id="input3"
                maxlength="4" value="#{phoneNumberTO.phoneSuffix}"
                >
                <f:validator validatorId="phoneValidator"  />
                <f:attribute name="phonePrefix" value="#{phonePrefix}"   /> 
             <f:attribute name="phoneAreaCode" value="#{phoneAreaCode}"   />
                             <f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirm}"   />
            </h:inputText>
             <h:inputSecret id="confirm" binding="#{confirm}" required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>

</div>



    </div>
```

Comment: You're insinuating that this works when you don't put them in different divs. Is this really the case? In other words, when you remove all those divs and other noise, it works?

Comment: Yes BaluCs . it works if i put in within same div consequitively one after the other.

Comment: This is strange. The code posted so far looks fine. So either you misinterpreted the problem, or the code does not represent the concrete problem at all (i.e. you oversimplified it).

Comment: You should try to create the *smallest possible* (so no noise like  `maxlength`, `class`, `stlyeClass`, irrelevant `<p>`/`<div>`, etc) but *complete* code which we should be able to just copy'n'paste'n'run without changes to see the problem ourselves.

Comment: Sorry , my missed some code ,see the code now . I have three divs "phone1" , "phone2" , "phone3" ,I would like to validate in the field "phone3" across these three fields. The validator doesn't get the submitted values of left and middle fields .I added the extra input field "confirm" inside the div "phone3" and the validtor gets the value of the "confirm" field.

Comment: To come back on *"it works if i put in within same div consequitively one after the other"* did you test that inside or outside the composite component?

Comment: i tested outside the componsite component,I didn't use any composite component . Please look at the code i updated in my actual post

Comment: But the presence of `#{cc.attrs.xxx}` suggests that this code is inside a composite component, because `#{cc}` is only available inside a composite component.

Comment: It was a typo and i am not using that <f:attribute name="validatorMessage"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.validatorMessage}" />
                <f:attribute name="converterMessage"
                    value="#{cc.attrs.converterMessage}" />

Comment: Okay. When you tested it outside the divs, did you also use `immediate="true"` on the first two components? That would be my main suspect, but that depends on how exactly you're collecting values from other components.

Comment: I re-confimed it ,i used immediate=true on the first two components. Otherwise it would be validated and submittedValue becomes NULL . I also tried putting the validator in the first div ,even then also it returns null for the below div inputs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11439/discussion-between-user684434-and-balusc)

Comment: Sorry, I don't participate in chat. But I now see the cause and I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I used `immediate=true` on the first two components. Otherwise it would be validated and submittedValue becomes NULL*

No, this is not what `immediate="true"` is for. Remove it.

In JSF, components are processed and converted/validated in the order as they appear in the JSF component tree. Every single input component is step-by-step converted and validated during *Validations Phase* as follows:

- Get component's submitted value by `UIInput#getSubmittedValue()`
- Convert component's submitted value to temp value.
- Validate temp value.

  - If validation succeeds, store temp value as component's value by `UIInput#setValue()` **and** set the component's submitted value to `null` by `UIInput#setSubmittedValue()`.
  - If validation fails, discard the temp value and set the component invalid by passing `false` to `UIInput#isValid()`. Note that the submitted value is kept on the component!

In the order as you have it in your view, with the validator on the *last* component, you should be collecting values of other inputs by `UIInput#getValue()` instead of `UIInput#getSubmittedValue()`, otherwise you will indeed keep getting `null`s when the validation has succeed for them.

```
UIInput phonePrefix = (UIInput) component.getAttributes().get("phonePrefix");
Object value = phonePrefix.getValue(); // Don't use getSubmittedValue().
```

As of now I can't explain why it worked when you have put them outside the divs. I think that you have actually accidently rearranged the order of the components.

---

As to the proper usage of `immediate="true"` attribute, it should help if you understand what exactly it does. Here's an extract of relevance from the [debug JSF lifecycle article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute):

> ### Okay, when should I use the immediate attribute?
>
> If it isn't entirely clear yet, here's a summary, complete with real world use examples when they may be beneficial:
>
> - If set in `UIInput`(s) only, the process validations phase will be taken place in apply request values phase instead. Use this to prioritize validation for the `UIInput` component(s) in question. When validation/conversion fails for any of them, the non-immediate components won't be validated/converted.
> - If set in `UICommand` only, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s). Use this to skip the entire processing of the form. E.g. "Cancel" or "Back" button.
> - If set in both `UIInput` and `UICommand` components, the apply request values phase until with update model values phases will be skipped for any of the `UIInput` component(s) which does not have this attribute set. Use this to skip the processing of the entire form expect for certain fields (with immediate). E.g. "Password forgotten" button in a login form with a required but non-immediate password field.